# Collect computers spec & antivirus information over domain network

Tags: help-desk

We are a company with over 1000 desktop and laptops joined domain network. I as HelpDesk expert would like to know if there is any software that help me to collect informations about all clients over network such as:

- OS version
- Windows last time updated
- Computer specs : cpu,ram,hdd
- AntiVirus details: name, version, last time updated

Comment: Complete soltions or DIY?  For DIY Powershell and/or WMI scripting

Comment: @mhesabi - What did you find? Need something similar.